# Prove this $\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}(n-|S|) \pi(S)=(n+1) !\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac {1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, stochastic-calculus, problem-solving

Set the natural number $n$. For each $S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}$ define $\pi(S)$ as the product of the members of $S$, with the agreement $\pi(\emptyset)=1$. Prove that
$$
\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}(n-|S|) \pi(S)=(n+1) !\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac {1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
$$

My working: I've worked on the right side so that the result is like this $$(n+1) !\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac {1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+ 1}\right)
$$
$$(n+1)!$$$$
\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}(n+1) !\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
$$
$$
\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}(n+1)n !\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
$$
$$
\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}n !
$$
I don't know if my method is correct or not, please help and correct it

Comment: Your RHS is invalid. Try for  small $n$.

Comment: And what is $S$ to do with the sum in RHS

Comment: You edit your question so it can not be seen what have you actualy done.

Comment: Please stop editing this!

Comment: Do not edit your question so that it changes its meaning.  If you have a new question to ask, use the "Ask Question" button to post a that question.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the comment your idea is not correct.

---

The formula you have to prove resembles Vieta's formulas, so we try with defining polynomial with roots $-1,-2,...-n$

Let $$A(x) = \sum_{S}\pi(S)x^{n-|S|}$$
Clearly $$A(x) = (x+1)(x+2)\cdots (x+n)$$ so $A(1) = (n+1)!$ and  $$\ln(A(x)) = \ln (x+1)+\ln(x+2)\cdots \ln(x+n)$$ so $${A'(x)\over A(x)} = {1\over x+1}+{1\over x+2}+\cdots {1\over x+n}$$

So $$A'(1) = A(1)\Big({1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+\cdots {1\over n+1}\Big)$$
$$\boxed{A'(1) = (n+1)!\Big({1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+\cdots {1\over n+1}\Big)}$$

But, on the other hand we have
$$A'(x) = \sum_{S}(n-|S|)\pi(S)x^{n-|S|-1}$$ and we are done since $$\boxed{A'(1) = \sum_{S}(n-|S|)\pi(S)}$$

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is not correct because
$$\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}(n+1) !\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)
=\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}n!=n!\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}1=n!\cdot 2^n$$
which is not equal to right-hand side $(n+1) !\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac {1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+ 1}\right)$.

Instead, consider the generating function
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}\pi(S)x^{|S|}$$
then it is easy to verify by induction that $$f_n(x)=\prod_{j=1}^n(1+jx).$$
Indeed $f_1(x)=\pi(\emptyset)x^{|\emptyset|}+\pi(\{1\})x^{|\{1\}|}=1+x$ and for $n>1$,
$$\begin{align}
f_n(x)&=\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n-1\}}\pi(S)x^{|S|}
+\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n-1\}}\pi(S\cup\{n\})x^{|S\cup\{n\}|}\\
&=f_{n-1}(x)+nxf_{n-1}(x)=f_{n-1}(x)(1+nx).
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}(n-|S|) \pi(S)&=
n\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}\pi(S)-\sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}|S| \pi(S)\\
&=nf_n(1)-f'_n(1)\\
&=nf_n(1)-f_n(1)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{3}+\dots+\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\\
&=(n+1)!\left(n-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{3}-\dots-\frac{n}{n+1}\right)\\
&=(n+1) !\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac {1}{3}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n+1}\right).
\end{align}$$
Notice that, according to the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#Product_of_more_than_two_factors), $$f'_n(x)=f_n(x)\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{(1+jx)'}{1+jx}=f_n(x)\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{j}{1+jx}.$$